# sql query NVL string with apostrophes (')

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

So I have an sql query i am currently working on that is like this:

```
SELECT * from tableA where 
( status = NVL('','OPEN') or status = NVL('','CLOSED') )
and delete_flag != 'Y'
```

The above query works fine and gives me the result I want.. but I was wondering if there is anyway I can combine the above status IN NVL line to one instead of using the or there.

for example, I want to be able to do:

```
SELECT * from tableA where 
status IN NVL('','OPEN','CLOSED')
and delete_flag != 'Y'
```

But the apostrophes are not working with me here.. how can I work around it?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @vkp i am trying to see if i can combine the two status = statements to one line like in the example i showed..

Comment: sorry.. does that make sense?...

Comment: NVL(colvalue, tothatvalue), so NVL is to subtitle NULL values to some value

Comment: Why not `status IN ('OPEN','CLOSED')` ?

Comment: @Thomas my tothatvalue is " 'OPEN','CLOSED' " how can i put that in there? when I do it in toad, its complaining that i have too many arguments...

Comment: yes, NVL() can have only two parameter

Comment: I need to use NVL.. cuz i have a drop down that will either be OPEN or CLOSED.. so if nothing is selected i want both..

Comment: `NVL('','OPEN')` will _always_ return`OPEN` as `''` is not null.  What are you intending to do with the `NVL` function?  Do you mean `WHERE status  IS NULL or status IN ('OPEN','CLOSED')`?

Comment: How does the value from the dropdown get into your query?

Comment: Apparently you have a few questions, which are only superficially related. What do you want to select - if status is NULL (or '') do you want the row selected, or not? If not, you can simply have IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED'). If you want to allow NULL, it is better to write WHERE status IS NULL OR status IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED'); don't use functions on status, which may prevent use of indexes. Then, you want to know if you can combine two NVL's into one. The answer is NO. And then there is the real issue, of allowing invalid inputs, like NULL when either OPEN or CLOSED should be selected...

Comment: i think psj01 does not want to select NULL values in status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an input parameter from your application that can have the values "Open", "Closed" or null

You want to be able to select status values that equal this input paremeter if it is null or the value of the input if it isn't.

To have null for a filter default to all you use COALESCE and the column you are filtering on.

Like this

```
SELECT * from tableA
where COALESCE(parameter,status) = status
  and status in ('OPEN','CLOSED') -- see comments
  and delete_flag != 'Y'
```

In this case if parameter is OPEN you will get all OPEN items, if parameter is CLOSED you will get all closed items and if it is null you will get all items.

This is a very common pattern in web applications.

---

Single line version

```
SELECT * from tableA
where COALESCE(parameter,CASE WHEN status in ('OPEN','CLOSED') then status ELSE '' END) = status
  and delete_flag != 'Y'
```

Comment: That works as long as the OP is passing in 'OPEN', 'CLOSED' or '' and status is non-nullable

Comment: @hogan that sort of works.. but if its null I want only 'OPEN' and 'CLOSED' items..  status have other values as well...

Comment: I was just about to type that here.. Thanks. that gives me the result I want.. but back to my original question.. so there is no way I can just do it in a single line ? like status IN NVL('','OPEN','CLOSED') ??

Comment: @psj01 I made a single line version -- but I don't think it is simple.

Comment: @psj01 - yw.  in SQL coalesce is used a lot ... learn to love it! :D

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
SELECT * from tableA 
 where 1=1
   and  nvl(status, '---') IN ('OPEN','CLOSED') 
   and delete_flag != 'Y'
```

Comment: Why `1=1` and why use `NVL` at all? If the status is `NULL` and it is not `IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSED')` so the row will not be included - exactly the same as if you tests for `'---'`.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle an empty string `''` is equivalent to `NULL`.

So `NVL( '', 'OPEN' )` is the equivalent to `NVL( NULL, 'OPEN' )` which can be simplified to just `'OPEN'`.

So your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
WHERE  ( status = 'OPEN' OR status = 'CLOSED' )
AND    delete_flag != 'Y'
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA
WHERE  status IN ( 'OPEN', 'CLOSED' )
AND    delete_flag != 'Y'
```

You can implement a dynamic list of options using a collection:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/

SELECT a.*
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT stringlist( 'OPEN', 'CLOSED' ) AS options FROM DUAL ) o
       ON ( o.options IS EMPTY OR a.status MEMBER OF o.options )
WHERE  a.delete_flag <> 'Y'
```

Comment: Yes. but i am having the user , select open or closed from a drop down list.. and if the user do not select either open or closed.. then i want to select all rows where status is either in open or closed status.. which is why i am using NVL('','xyz'), if the user selects nothing then its '' and i want it replaced with xyz..   Note: there are other status in the table other than open /closed..

Comment: @psj01 Then you ought to state that in the question.

Comment: yes i realize the question is kind of unclear.. but i wasn't sure how to word it correctly.. sorry about that.

Comment: Do you know if I can do what I want in a single like using NVL?